# failed attempt of using boost::optional

Tags: c++, boost-optional

I have been trying to use boost optional for a function that could either return an object or a null and I cant figure it out. Here is what I have so far. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

```
class Myclass
{
public:
    int a;
};

boost::optional<Myclass> func(int a)  //This could either return MyClass or a null
{
    boost::optional<Myclass> value;
    if(a==0)
    {
        //return an object
            boost::optional<Myclass> value;
        value->a = 200;

    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    boost::optional<Myclass> v = func(0);
    //How do I check if its a NULL or an object

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

This is my new code and I am getting a compiler error at `value = {200};`

```
class Myclass
{
public:
    int a;
};

boost::optional<Myclass> func(int a)
{
    boost::optional<Myclass> value;
    if(a == 0)
        value = {200};

    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    boost::optional<Myclass> v = func(0);


    if(v)
        std::cout << v -> a << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Uninitilized" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your function should look like following:

```
boost::optional<Myclass> func(int a)
{
    boost::optional<Myclass> value;
    if(a == 0)
        value = {200};

    return value;
}
```

And you could check it by casting to `bool`:

```
boost::optional<Myclass> v = func(42);
if(v)
    std::cout << v -> a << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "Uninitilized" << std::endl;
```

---

> Isnt it going to be value->a = 200

No, it isn't. From [Boost.Optional.Docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/detailed_semantics.html):

> ```
> T const* optional<T (not a ref)>::operator ->() const ;
>
> T* optional<T (not a ref)>::operator ->() ;
> ```
>
> - **Requirements: *this is initialized**.
> - Returns: A pointer to the contained value.
> - Throws: Nothing.
> - Notes: The requirement is asserted via BOOST_ASSERT().

And in the `operator->` definition:

```
pointer_const_type operator->() const
{
    BOOST_ASSERT(this->is_initialized());
    return this->get_ptr_impl();
}
```

If object is not initialized, assertion will be failed. When we write

```
value = {200};
```

We initialize value with `Myclass{200}`.

---

Note, that `value = {200}` requires support for initializer lists(C++11 feature). If your compiler doesn't support it, you could use it like this:

```
Myclass c;
c.a = 200;
value = c;
```

Or provide constructor for `Myclass` with `int` as argument:

```
Myclass(int a_): a(a_)
{

}
```

Then you could just write

```
value = 200;
```

Comment: I am confused with `value = {200}` Isnt it going to be `value->a = 200` ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But with `value = {200};` I get the compile error during building `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'`

Comment: With this code, you would still end up with /usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:1117: boost::optional::pointer_type boost::optional::operator->() [with T = Myclass; boost::optional::pointer_type = Myclass*]: Assertion `this->is_initialized()' failed. Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: /* This results in the runtime error mentioned above */
            value->a = {200};

           /* The following #if 0 , if used instead would remove the error */
#if 0 
            Myclass c;
            c.a = 200;
            value = c;
#endif